# ResourceDictionary can't find DataType for the DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, namespaces, resourcedictionary

I have to outsource my DataTemplates to a ResourceDictionary. Everything works fine, except detecting the DataTypes of the DataTemplates.

In order to get the ResourceDictionary I wrote following function:

```
public static ResourceDictionary ParseResourceDictionary(String path)
{
        System.Windows.ResourceDictionary templates = new System.Windows.ResourceDictionary();
        templates = new System.Windows.ResourceDictionary() { Source = new System.Uri(path) };
        return templates;
}
```

My ResourceDictionary looks like that:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:ResourceDictTest;assembly=ResourceDictTest"
>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:Company}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

If I get the dictionary via my function, I got the exception, that
the DataType "Company" can't be found in classes, but when I write "classes:" Company will get suggested, so the namespace isn't wrong at all.

The error message would be something like that (not my native language):

**No public type with the name "Company" can be found.**

And yes, the class "Company" is set to public.

Before this, I tried:

```
xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:ResourceDictTest"
```

Instead of this:

```
xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:ResourceDictTest;assembly=ResourceDictTest"
```

And got the message, that there was an error creating a Type out of "classes:Company".

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried getting the ResourceDictionary via XAML?

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ResourceDictTest.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I haven't. Do I have to add the whole path into source? Like C:\Users\...\ResourceDictTest.xaml? I tried it like that and the error still occurs. I really don't know what's wrong.

Comment: You have to set it relative to the Project root.

Comment: So if my project is called "ResourceDictTest", I have to put the ResourceDictionary in \ResourceDictTest ? I have another folder called "Templates" so my path is sth like that: C:\Users\...\ResourceDictTest\Templates\ResourceDictText.xaml. I don't know exactly what you mean by that. It's not my native language. €dit: I tried Templates\ResourceDict.Text.xaml now, but it still aint working.

Comment: yes in your case "Templates/ResourceDict.Text.xaml" should be right in case you include the dictionary in your "App.xaml". For your other problem: in what namespace is your Company class? Have you tried to clean your solution and rebuild yet?

Comment: Thanks Ian! I have added the dictionary in App.xaml as you said and the error still occured. Then I tried to get the dictionary via "App.Current.Resources as ResourceDictionary" instead of parsing it with my function. Now everything gets loaded without a problem! I upvoted your answer, but I haven't the priviledges right now. Thank you very much!